# How to write a loop that locates a specific value in a column, if it finds one, write a formula to an adjacent cell, then continue

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop through a column looking for a specific value, if it finds that value, then write a formula in an adjacent cell, that happens to sum some values in another column.

I've tried writing my own loops, but I keep getting error after error.

If you look at the photo in the link you can see a small dataset.

Here is my explanation of what I am trying to code:

1. Loop through column C
2. When you find the value "Header"
3. Count down how many cells until you reach the next value of "Header"
4. Store that # as a variable
5. Insert a formula in column D that sums the values in column B from the first "Header" down however many rows that are saved in the variable
6. Write that range in the adjacent cell for each "Header"

This code would also ideally have a way that when it got to the bottom, it would not run indefinitely. And if a "Header" row was on the bottom, it would still just Sum itself, and still, write the value over to the total.

[My sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCloo.png)

EDIT 1 -

I don't think I'm on the right path here but this is what I started with. This tries to figure out how many cells between the values of "Header". It works, but I don't know how to integrate it inside another function. I have it set to ActiveCell.Row just for testing so I could try it with a larger data set. It also doesn't return a value if the last row is header, it just keeps looking until the bottom and finds nothing.

```
Function CountRows() As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Counter As Integer

Set sht = ActiveSheet 'Sets this sheet as active
LastRow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row 'Sets to count down the rows, on Column C

For i = ActiveCell.Row + 1 To LastRow ' Sets which Row the macro starts at before heading down
    If sht.Cells(i, "C").Value <> "Header" Then  'Looking for "Header" in column C
        Counter = Counter + 1
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
CountRows = Counter + 1
MsgBox Counter


End Function
```

Edit 2 - This is what I imagined the output formula would be.

```
Sub WriteFormula()
Range("Adjacent Cell To Header").Formula = "=SUM("B" & "Row # it found "Header" in" & ":" & "B" & "Row # it found "Header" in + Variable")"
End Sub
```

Comment: What code have you tried, and where did you encounter problems with it?

Comment: What have you tried?  We're glad to help you fix what you have, but we need a starting point to work with.

Comment: I updated my initial post to show what code I currently have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit easier if you work from the bottom up:

```
Sub Summarize()

    Dim r As Long, rLast As Long, sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    r = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    rLast = r

    Do
        If sht.Cells(r, "C").Value = "Header" Then
            sht.Cells(r, "D").Formula = "=SUM(B" & r & ":B" & rLast & ")"
            rLast = r - 1
        End If
        r = r - 1
    Loop While r > 1

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim Williams, it works fantastic and starting from the bottom up makes more sense.

Comment: If I wanted to start this code on say row 8, could you help me do that? I have tried to replacing the .Cells to have something like .Range(Cells(8 , "C"), Cells(r, "C"), but keep getting errors.

Comment: The processing move up from the last row, so do you mean use row 8 as the starting point, or as the stopping point?

Comment: I believe row 8 should be the stopping point, since we are counting from the bottom. So if there were a value of "Header" in Rows 1-7 (Column C), they would essentially be ignored.

Comment: `Loop While r > 7` should do it

Comment: Awesome Tim, way too simple. I should have read through the entire code before diving in to where I thought the solution had to be. Thanks